# Laravel edit pagination next and previous url for filtering

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am trying to create infinite scroll in laravel for that I am using default pagination and it is working fine but I want a pagination to use filtering.

```
public function infinite_scroll(Request $request)
{
    $key = $request->input('key');
    $group_name = $request->input('groupname');
    $wachat = Wechat::where('key', '=', $key)->where('groupName', '=', $group_name)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(2);
    $this->response['values'] = $wachat;
    $this->response['key'] = $key;
    return response()->json(
        $this->response
    );
}
```

I am using this code and it is giving me this url in next url:

```
next_page_url: "http://localhost:8888/kc/kyo-webservice/public/api/v1/wechatinfinite?page=2"
```

But I want a filtering based on key and groupname for example when I pass a param groupname and key it should give me values.

When I am trying to get next page url it is not working I want my result for pagination based on my filter it should give me next page url like this:

```
next_page_url: "http://localhost:8888/kc/kyo-webservice/public/api/v1/wechatinfinite??key=smg1np1f77&groupname=group&page=2"
```

And it should give me result based on my filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used [`appends()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) pagination method here

**Appending To Pagination Links**

> You may append to the query string of pagination links using the
>   appends method. For example, to append sort=votes to each pagination
>   link, you should make the following call to  appends:

```
$wachat->appends(['key'=> $key,'groupname' => $group_name]);
```

in your controller do like that

```
public function infinite_scroll(Request $request)
{
    $key = $request->input('key');
    $group_name = $request->input('groupname');
    $wachat = Wechat::where('key', '=', $key)->where('groupName', '=', $group_name)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(2);
    $wachat->appends(['key'=> $key,'groupname' => $group_name]);
    $this->response['values'] = $wachat;
    $this->response['key'] = $key;
    return response()->json(
        $this->response
    );
}
```